# MPI in Windows (returning data from slave task to master task)

Tags: c, mpi, multitasking

I am in the process of learning how to use MPI.

Right now all I am trying to do is send and receive data between the master task and the slave tasks. Sending data from the master task to the slave tasks works correctly. (I tested this by having each slave print the data they received from the master).

Receiving data in the master task from the slave tasks doesn't seem to work.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MASTER_TAG 0    
#define WORKTAG 1
#define DIETAG 2

#define N 4
#define ARRAY_SIZE N*N

int getMin(int a, int b);
void print1D(int *arr, int n);
int* allocateIntegerArray(int n);
void master();
void slave();

int *inputArray = NULL;
int *outputArray = NULL;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int myrank = 0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); // initialize MPI

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank); // process rank, 0 thru N-1

    if (myrank == 0)
        master();
    else
        slave();

    MPI_Finalize(); // cleanup MPI

    return 0;
}

void master()
{
    int numOfTasks;
    int rank = 0;
    int work = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int dataPerTask = 0;
    int *tempArray = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numOfTasks); // #processes in application

    // calculate the amount of data that each task will receive
    dataPerTask = ARRAY_SIZE;

    // create the array that will hold the data that will be transferred back and forth between the master and slave tasks
    tempArray = allocateIntegerArray( dataPerTask );

    for (i = 1; i < numOfTasks; ++i)
    {
        MPI_Send(&dataPerTask, 1, MPI_INT, i, WORKTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // send the size of the data chunk to the slave task
        MPI_Send(tempArray, dataPerTask, MPI_INT, i, WORKTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // send the actual chunk of data to the slave task

        print1D(tempArray, dataPerTask);
        MPI_Recv(tempArray, dataPerTask, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_TAG, WORKTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // receive results from slave task
        print1D(tempArray, dataPerTask);
    }

    // tell all the slaves to exit
    for (i = 1; i < numOfTasks; ++i)
        MPI_Send(0, 0, MPI_INT, i, DIETAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    free(tempArray);
}

void slave()
{
    MPI_Status status;
    int *in = NULL; // input array
    int *out = NULL; // outpu array
    int dataPerTask = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        MPI_Recv(&dataPerTask, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER_TAG, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // get the number of integers in the incoming array

        if (status.MPI_TAG == DIETAG) // check the tag of the received message (if the master task sent the DIETAG, then the slave must stop processing and return)
            return;

        in = allocateIntegerArray(dataPerTask); // array 'in' holds the data received from the master task
        out = allocateIntegerArray(dataPerTask); // array 'out' holds the data that is returned to the master task

        MPI_Recv(in, dataPerTask, MPI_INT, MASTER_TAG, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); // get the actual data from the master task

        out[0] = 1; // modify the data in some way
        MPI_Send(out, dataPerTask, MPI_INT, 0, WORKTAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    free(in);
    free(out);
}

void print1D(int *arr, int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    printf("\n");
}

int* allocateIntegerArray(int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    if (n <= 0)
        return NULL;

    int *arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n*n);
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof(int)*n*n);

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: please upload a [MCVE] that matches the issue you are facing (e.g. sending from slaves and not from master)

Comment: Hello. What more can I do to make code Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable? I removed a lot of code and left only what is required to reproduce the problem. The code I posted demonstrates that I am able to send data to the slaves but not receive data from them in the master task. Should I delete the slave()/master() functions and insert their code in main()? I thought this way made it more readable.

Comment: I might have misread your problem description, let me have a look at the code from now.

Comment: the code works for me. what makes you think *it doesn't seem to work* ?

Comment: fwiw, you can replace `allocateIntegerArray()` with a standard `calloc()`

Comment: In the master() function, inside the first loop, I am printing the array "tempArray" before and after I call MPI_Recv() and the results are identical (all zeroes). The slave tasks are setting the first element of the array that they are sending to the master task to 1. EDIT: will replace malloc()/memset() with calloc(), thanks

Comment: this is not what I get. The first line is all zeros, then the following lines start with a `1` followed by several `0`, so bottom line, the program behaves correctly as far as i can tell.

Comment: May I ask how are you running the code? I compile the code with VS2015, then use "mpiexec -n 4 app.exe" from the command prompt and I get six lines of zeroes.

Comment: I use `Open MPI` under Linux fwiw. note you should not `MPI_Recv()` with `MPI_ANY_TAG`, but `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` or `i` on `master` and `0` on slaves. Try fixing that and see how it helps.

Comment: I replaced the 'MPI_ANY_TAG' with 'i' and I get exactly what you get. I thought that 'MPI_ANY_TAG and 'MPI_ANY_SOURCE' had the same effect. Thanks for the help. Could you post your last comment in the form of an answer? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause is your program calls `MPI_Recv(...,source=MPI_ANY_TAG, ...)`

`MPI_ANY_TAG` is not a valid source, and you should use a proper source (e.g. `i` in `master`, and `0` in `slave`) or `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`.

FWIW, and do **not** take this for granted since it might change in the future

- in `Open MPI`, `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` and `MPI_ANY_TAG` have the same value, that's why I initially thought it worked for me.
- in `MPICH`, `MPI_ANY_TAG` have the same value than `MPI_PROC_NULL`, and that is why messages had only zeros in your environment.